# Linq query to get a list of products, each with a list of identifiers and a list of properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a list of products with a common `ProductGroupId`. Each product has any number of identifiers (things like product number, EAN, ISBN, etc.) and any number of properties (things like colour, height, size, etc). Each property has any number of selectable options (like "red", "green", etc. for colour).

The products are stored in `Products`.

The identifier labels ("EAN", "ISBN", etc.) are stored in `ProductIdentifiers`, and the product's value for an identifier is stored in `IdentifiersForProducts`. E.g.: EAN (label) : 7044304034373 (value).

The property labels (e.g. "Colour") are stored in `ProductProperties`, the available options for a property ("Red", "Green", etc.) are stored in `ProductPropertyOptions`, and the product's selected option-id for a particular property is stored in `PropertyOptionsForProducts`.

Here are the models:

**Product**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
    public int ProductGroupSortOrder { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string LongInfo { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }


    // Selected property options for this product
    public ICollection<PropertyOptionForProduct> ProductPropertyOptionForProducts { get; set; }

    // Product identifiers (EAN, ISBN, product number, etc.)
    public ICollection<IdentifierForProduct> IdentifierForProducts { get; set; }

    // ... some more properties
}
```

**Identifiers**

```
public class ProductIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public List<IdentifierForProduct> ProductIdentifiers { get; set; }
}

public class IdentifierForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductIdentifierId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ProductIdentifier ProductIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

**Properties**

```
public class ProductProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; } // E.g. "Battery capacity"
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; } // E.g. "mA"
    public bool AllowMultipleSelections { get; set; }
    public int OptionType { get; set; } // string, single number or from-to range?
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    // A property can have multiple options
    public List<ProductPropertyOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPropertyOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public decimal NumberValue { get; set; }
    public decimal RangeFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal RangeTo { get; set; }

    public ProductProperty Property { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PropertyOptionForProduct> PropertyOptionForProducts { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyOptionForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyOptionId { get; set; }

    // Nav.props.
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductPropertyOption ProductPropertyOption { get; set; }
}
```

My current Frankenstein's monster-query looks like this:

```
List<Product> GroupMembers = await (
    from prod in _context.Products
    join ident in _context.IdentifiersForProducts on prod.Id equals ident.ProductId
    join prop in _context.PropertyOptionsForProducts on prod.Id equals prop.ProductId
    where
        prod.ProductGroupId == groupId &&
        prod.Id == ident.ProductId &&
        prod.Id == prop.ProductId
    select prod)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(o => o.ProductGroupSortOrder)
    .ToListAsync();
```

I have also tried something simpler:

```
List<Product> GroupMembers =
        await _context.Products
            .Include(i => i.IdentifierForProducts)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductIdentifier)
            .Include(po => po.ProductPropertyOptionForProducts)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.ProductPropertyOption)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Property)
            .Where(g => g.ProductGroupId == groupId)
        .OrderBy(o => o.ProductGroupSortOrder)
        .ToListAsync();
```

... but the result was pretty much the same, and not correct. It seems I'm getting all the identifiers for all the products in the group on each product, so that for example one product in the group gets a list of product numbers, each belonging to each of the products in the group. And I'm not getting any properties from either of the two queries.

Comment: In the 1st query, you repeat the join conditions in the where clause...

Comment: The 2nd query looks OK, but we can't see your model buildup.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Maybe it looks ok, but it's not giving me the result I'm after. Every product gets it's own AND every other product's identifiers. And no product gets any properties. I'm not sure what you mean by model buildup.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have checked the database. First I created one single product and gave it one identifier. When I cloned the product to the group, there were two products in the database with one identifier each. But in the group list, each product were displaying both the identifier of product 1 and product 2. When I cloned the product again, making the group list contain three products, each product displayed the identifier of product 1, 2, and 3. And so on. Still, in the database, each product only have one identifier.

Comment: I can't help you any further, if you want help from this site i would advise setting up a [mcve]. Keep it small and simple.